# How to override M2M field names and models in Django with an existing database?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, field

I'm using Django 3.1.3 and working with an existing postgresql database. Most of the models and fields names of this DB are badly chosen and/or way too long. Most of the time its easy to change them with some handy Django options like so :

```
class NewModelName(models.Models):

    new_field_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column='old_field_name')

    class Meta:
        managed=False
        db_table='database_old_table_name'
```

But let say I want to change a M2M field name and the corresponding model name. I'd like to have something like :

```
class Foo(models.Models):

    new_m2m_field_name = models.ManyToManyField('RelatedModel', blank=True, db_column='old_m2m_field_name')

    class Meta:
        managed=False
        db_table='foo_old_table_name'


class RelatedModel(models.Models):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        managed=False
        db_table='related_model_old_table_name'
```

But if I do that, Django will throw an error stating
`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "foo_new_m2m_field_name" does not exist`. It is like it is ignoring the `db_column` option. Any idea how I could get to a similar result ?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no column in table for many to many relation but the additional pivot table, do you understand the concept of this type of ER modeling?

Comment: Thanks @iklinac, I think I do, there is no column but a join table between both models, what I am trying to do is telling django to actually use this join table when I call the `new_m2m_field_name` on a `Foo` instance

Answer (score 2):

From Django documentation regarding [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield)

> `ManyToManyField.db_table` The name of the table to create for storing
> the many-to-many data. If this is not provided, Django will assume a
> default name based upon the names of: the table for the model defining
> the relationship and the name of the field itself.

Also depending on column names (non standard names) in original database you might have to define through model ( pivot table) as [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) table

Answer (score 1):

You could add a property `db_table` ([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield))

linking to the previous table, named `foo_old_table_name`  in your case.
According to the doc,

> By default, this table name is generated using the name of the
> many-to-many field and the name of the table for the model that
> contains it

So for the field `new_m2m_field_name`, the previous table making the link was named : `old_field_name_database_old_table_name`.
Hence :

```
new_field_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column='old_field_name', db_table='old_field_name_database_old_table_name')
```

The option `through` could be changed too, but I do not think it is necessary if the modifications on names are coherent.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to manually define the Through model (that Django would otherwise implicitly create behind the scenes) in order to make it unmanaged.

```
class Foo(models.Models):

    new_m2m_field_name = models.ManyToManyField(
        "RelatedModel",
        blank=True,
        db_column="old_m2m_field_name",
        through="FooRelatedJoin",  # <- new
    )

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "foo_old_table_name"


class RelatedModel(models.Models):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "related_model_old_table_name"


class FooRelatedJoin(models.Models):  # <- all new
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    related_model = models.ForeignKey(RelatedModel)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "foo_join_table"
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed! The `db_column` option in `Foo` model is not necessary here